# Trying to run gdal:polygonize on all .img files in directory

Tags: pyqgis, gdal-polygonize

In QGIS PY console, I'm attempting to run gdal:polygonize as a subprocess in order convert all files in a directory into ESRI shapefiles. Using the code below and receiving the error that follows.

```
import subprocess
import glob
import os
import gdal

for f in glob.glob("D:/QGIS_depot/raster/*.img"):
    out_file = f[:-4] + ".shp"
    in_file = os.path.join("D:/QGIS_depot/raster/", f)
    cmdline = processing.run("gdal:polygonize", {'INPUT':in_file,'BAND':1,'FIELD':'DN','EIGHT_CONNECTEDNESS':False,'EXTRA':'','OUTPUT':out_file})
    subprocess.call(cmdline)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.14\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
exec(code, self.locals)
File "", line 1, in 
File "", line 10, in 
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.14\apps\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 304, in call
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.14\apps\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 756, in **init**
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.14\apps\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1155, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: `gdal:polygonize` is a QGIS Processing alg, not a command line tool. You either want [`gdal_polygonize.py`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_polygonize.html) or `processing.run('gdal:polygonize', {args dict})`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. 

I've adjusted my code to use processing.run('gdal:polygonize'

Now using the following code I am able to polygonize 1 .img file but receiving an error when the next .img is supposed to process.

Comment: I've updated my original post to have the new code and traceback error

Comment: `gdal:polygonize` is a QGIS Processing alg, not a command line tool. You don't use `subprocess.call` at all.